# Batch processing DEM rasters in QGIS/GDAL

Tags: qgis, gdal, dem

I am attempting to add relief shading to map using .asc raster files, following [this tutorial](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/03/working-with-terrain-data-in-qgis.html). It works well, but I have only tried it on single tile of raster data which is 20x20km. I want to generate the shading for a much larger area, which means multiple tiles.

I understand I can input GDAL commands in the Hillshade/DEM dialogue in QGIS, and the tutorial suggests this means I can perform a batch operation, but I don't know enough (read any) GDAL to do this.

I am using QGIS 1.9 on Ubuntu (though I do have a Windows installation as well).

Any ideas?

EDIT: I have written the following script, demraster.sh:

```
!/bin/sh 
for f in *.asc 
do
echo "Processing %f" 
gdaldem hillshade %f -z 1.0 -s 1.0 -az 315.0 -alt 45.0 
done
```

I have set it to be executable with **chmod**, and run it with **sh demraster.sh** but get a syntax error:

```
Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")
```

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1130892

Comment: Tried the suggestions in there, no luck.

Comment: Including the addition of semicolons as per @BradHards answer? Note the pound (`#`) prior to `!/bin/sh` also.  The next question - are you using a bash shell?

Comment: Tried BradHard's script: same error. I have no idea what shell I'm using. I have no idea what a shell is.

Comment: Done a bit of Googling. If I type echo $SHELL, it returns /bin/bash. I have tried to change shells with chsh, but when I do that and type echo $SHELL again, it still returns bash.

Comment: it seems everyone thinks it should be line endings maybe someone can put the scripts text file in a dropbox of sume sort and put a link here?
sorry i am on a windows machine and never used qgis scripting

Comment: It is easier to just use @MikeToews answer.  Type it in.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/48568/2695

Comment: In any case this isn't QGIS scripting, it's shell scripting. As a Windows user you should be able to install OSGeo4W and maybe Cygwin and do this anyway

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [dialog here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1130892), you might have some odd POSIX user permission stuff getting in the way. Or possibly DOS line endings (rather than UNIX). Rather than making a file, just do the loop from the command prompt, by typing it out in the terminal. I [do this routinely](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7806/1872), without the need of making a shell script file.

Typing this the first time, you should see the prompt character in the first column change from `$` to `>` (don't type these!) until the end of the loop block:

```
$ for f in *.asc
> do
> echo "Processing $f"
> gdaldem hillshade  -z 2.0 -az 345.0 -alt 50.0 $f $f-HS.tif
> done
```

(Note: this is identical to yours, except I replace `%f` with `$f`.) After this, you can type the <kbd>up</kbd> key to see the previous command.

```
for f in *.asc; do echo "Processing $f"; gdaldem hillshade  -z 2.0 -az 345.0 -alt 50.0 $f $f-HS.tif; done
```

It is shown as a one-line condensed version with semi-colons, which you can use and modify (if needed) for further work from the command prompt.

Comment: Inputting it manually worked! Though using @nhopton's script (yours is missing the destination files I think). Still can't get it run as a shell script though. But this is good enough for me. Thanks!

Comment: it's frustrating when simple things don't work one way, but work another way. I updated it to nhopton's command for completeness.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick. Make a text file with the following lines:

```
for f in *.asc
do
  echo "Processing $f"
gdaldem hillshade  -z 2.0 -az 345.0 -alt 50.0 $f $f-HS.tif
done
```

Save it with the extension .sh (for example "hillshade.sh"). Drop the file in the directory with your ASC rasters and then run it from a terminal: "sh hillshade.sh".

N.

Comment: I'll try this ASAP, hopefully it won't throw up a syntax error like the script in my question.

Comment: It shouldn't, I've just tested it on a directory of *.asc rasters. Just like yours possibly, 20 km x 20 km DTMs; Ordnance Survey OpenData? :)

Comment: No luck, I still get the error: demraster.sh: 2: demraster.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")

Comment: Is it something I have set up wrong in Ubuntu? Something to do with the shell? I am a total noob when it comes to Linux.

Comment: You've made the shell script executable, so that shouldn't be the problem. If you are copying the text from the answer and pasting this into the .sh file try typing the text instead (there might be a font encoding problem). The script as presented does work here (I'm also on Ubuntu). One other thing, make sure the raster files aren't in a directory with spaces in its name or in its path name.  N.

Comment: This script worked, inputting it 'manually' in the terminal rather than running it as a script

Comment: Ah, so it probably was a font encoding problem. It should also run as a shell script if you type the text into the .sh file. N.

Comment: @ElendilTheTall I'm guessing the file was in a so-called DOS format, rather than a UNIX format. This would be odd if you created the file using a Linux editor, but would definitely happen if you create it first on Windows.

Comment: I _did_ create it in Windows, trying it with OSGeo4W. I'll recreate it in Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: I _did_ create it in Windows, trying it with OSGeo4W. I'll recreate it in Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: DOS files can be converted to UNIX using several methods using `dos2unix` or [other methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613800/how-to-convert-dos-windows-newline-to-unix-newline-in-bash-script)

Comment: ah heck, it's only a few lines, I'll just start from scratch. But good to know.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the use the shell and gdaldem:

http://gdal.org/gdaldem.html

```
gdaldem hillshade in.asc out.tif
```

Comment: I absolutely do, but I have no idea how to. I have the necessary GDAL command (gdaldem hillshade %f -z 1.0 -s 1.0 -az 315.0 -alt 45.0, where %f is the file) but I have no idea how to run this on multiple files. I have very little Ubuntu/Linux experience.

Comment: Okay, I see.  Make a text file with one command on each line, call it dem.sh, then make it executable using:
chmod u+x dem.sh
and then run it: ./dem.sh
google simple shell scripting, and that should get you there.

Comment: or write a one line `for * do` command.  Here is a good example: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/42741/2695

Comment: I have #!/bin/sh
for f in *.asc
do
echo "Processing %f"
gdaldem hillshade %f -z 1.0 -s 1.0 -az 315.0 -alt 45.0
done but it gives me: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")

Comment: In other words Jay Laura, I have pretty much the command you linked to and it gives me that syntax error

Comment: Can you post the command in your question.  We can debug then hopefully.  Any error text as well please.

Comment: Done..............

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you are having issues with line endings - given that we have tried almost everything else.

I would use the script provided by @BradHards (copied below) and manually retype it on your system in either vi or nano.  My suggestion would be nano as you do not need to learn vi to get this working.

Step by step would be to:

1. Open a terminal and `cd` to the directory with your *.asc files.
2. execute the command `nano`
3. Retype the code below - do not cut and paste.
4. `control-x` to exit, name the file `batch_dem.sh` or something, and save it.
5. chmod +x batch_dem.sh
6. ./batch_dem.sh

   ```
   #!/bin/sh 
   for f in *.asc;
   do
   echo "Processing %f";
   gdaldem hillshade %f -z 1.0 -s 1.0 -az 315.0 -alt 45.0;
   done
   ```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways (i know) to handle this:

1. Using Bash commands (**for** loop)[only in **linux**]
2. Using scripting languages like Python (**for** loop)[**every system that installed Python**]

**Here is the code. You can modify it easily for linux**

```
import os

pathOfDems = 'F:/Gdem'

pathForHill = 'F:/Hillshade'

pathToGdalDem = 'C:/OSGeo4W/bin/gdaldem.exe'

dliste = os.listdir(pathOfDems)

for i in range (0,len(dliste),1):

os.system(pathToGdalDem + ' hillshade ' + pathOfDems + os.sep + dliste[i] + '    ' +  pathForHill + os.sep + 'Hillshade_' + dliste[i][8:-8] + '.tif')
```