# Up-sampling (increasing resolution) raster image using GDAL?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, resampling

I have a single-band geo-referenced raster image (a DEM) and my goal is to increase the number of pixels in each dimension (x and y) by 3. 
So given an initial resolution of 1200 * 1200 pixels, I want to upsample it to 3600 * 3600 pixels, keeping the geographic referencing.

This procedure is a part of a large batch processing so [simple gui workflow](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49638/how-to-increase-resolution-of-dem-rasters) is not an option and I'd like to do it programmatically, using `python gdal`.

What is the right way to do it and is there any interpolation required to do it?

Comment: In ArcGIS the tool is called Resample http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009t000000 I suggest you'll want to use Bilinear interpolation, cubic gouges valleys and enhances peaks..

Comment: If you also need an ArcPy answer after trying the above then please ask a new question with your code attempt.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following `gdal` script is useful to resample an image to a smaller pixel size:

```
import os
from osgeo import gdal

# Change working directory     
os.chdir("directory with rasters")

# Open raster and get band
in_ds = gdal.Open('raster')
in_band = in_ds.GetRasterBand(1)

# Multiply output size by 3 
out_rows = in_band.YSize * 3
out_columns = in_band.XSize * 3

# Create new data source (raster)
gtiff_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
out_ds = gtiff_driver.Create('band1_resampled.tif', out_columns, out_rows)
out_ds.SetProjection(in_ds.GetProjection())
geotransform = list(in_ds.GetGeoTransform())

# Edit the geotransform so pixels are one-sixth previous size
geotransform[1] /= 3
geotransform[5] /= 3
out_ds.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)

data = in_band.ReadAsArray(buf_xsize=out_columns, buf_ysize=out_rows)  # Specify a larger buffer size when reading data
out_band = out_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
out_band.WriteArray(data)

out_band.FlushCache()
out_band.ComputeStatistics(False)
out_ds.BuildOverviews('average', [2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64])

del out_ds
```

However, this script does not perform a specific interpolation and the result will look similar to the following picture (with a different resampling size):

[image]

**Note:** image taken from Geoprocessing with Python (by Chris Garrard) book. https://www.manning.com/books/geoprocessing-with-python

Furthermore, you could try using `gdal_translate` from the `gdal` command line utilities. (More info here: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)

As you need to do a large processing batch it is possible to use python along with this utility as the following example:

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir("directory with the rasters")

result = subprocess.call('gdal_translate -of GTiff -outsize 3600 3600 -r bilinear raster.tif raster_resample.tif')
```

where:

- `- of` specifies the output format.
- `-outsize` specifies the output size in pixels (xsize, ysize)
- `-r` specifies the resampling algorithm
- `raster.tif` is the input filename
- `raster_resample.tif` is the output filename.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use rasterio, these modules might help:

https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/resampling.html