# R dissagregate method in python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, r

It seems an easy question, but I can't find the Python equivalent of R's [Dissaggregate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/2.6-7/topics/disaggregate):

> Disaggregate a RasterLayer to create a new RasterLayer with a higher
>   resolution (smaller cells)

I expected it in GDAL but no luck so far.

Comment: Is this what you want to do? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/271226/up-sampling-increasing-resolution-raster-image-using-gdal

Comment: Actually, yes. So I assume in gdal there is no direct method to do so. Thanks for the hint, it will be easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might want something like `numpy.repeat`. Open the raster as a numpy array by doing `array = gdal.Open(file).ReadAsArray()`, then use `np.repeat` for both the x and y axes. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

>>> array = np.random.randint(10,size =(3,3))
>>> array
    array([[6, 1, 6],
           [9, 7, 0],
           [3, 1, 7]])
>>> downsampled_in_x = np.repeat(array,2,axis = 1)
>>> downsampled_in_x
    array([[6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 6],
           [9, 9, 7, 7, 0, 0],
           [3, 3, 1, 1, 7, 7]])
>>> downsampled_in_both = np.repeat(downsampled_in_x,2,axis = 0)
>>> downsampled_in_both
    array([[6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 6],
           [6, 6, 1, 1, 6, 6],
           [9, 9, 7, 7, 0, 0],
           [9, 9, 7, 7, 0, 0],
           [3, 3, 1, 1, 7, 7],
           [3, 3, 1, 1, 7, 7]])
```

See [numpy / scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) for more info

Note that this is different from resampling, which one could accomplish by using `gdal_translate` or similar.