# Run OTB commands in OSGeo4W Shell scripts

Tags: osgeo, orfeo-toolbox, shell

I am trying to run shell scripts with Orfeo-toolbox commands, and I'm new to all this.... (I'm working in Windows 7).

I can type

```
otbcli_ComputeImagesStatistics -il Imagery/P1_10cm1.tif Imagery/P2_10c1.tif -out ImageAnalysis/Stats12_JUNK3.xml
```

directly into the OSGeo4W shell window and things work fine. Now I'd like to put more commands in a script and run them all at once.

I'm following the advice from [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42734/how-to-run-osgo4w-shell-script-on-windows).

If I save that text in a file called `TryShell.sh` 
and enter in shell window:

```
sh TryShell.sh
```

I get the error `TryShell.sh: line 1: otbcli_ComputeImagesStatistics: command not found`

Why does the `otbcli` command work in the shell but not in the shell script?

Comment: My guess is that the location of the command's executable is not known to the operating system. Try adding its folder to your path. In the OSGeo3W shell, it has that information, thus the command works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working in person with a friend, I think I figured it out. It turns out you can save the commands in a `.bat` file and just type that file into the prompt in the OSGeo4W shell. This works without setting any path.

** The catch, is that it seems that commands like `otbcli_ComputeImagesStatistics` are themselves batch calls, so if I put more than one of them in the same .bat file it would only execute the first one.  The problem was solved by putting "call" on the line in front of the `otbcli_*` commands.

So to sum up, make a file `TEST.bat`, with commands like:

```
call otbcli_ComputeImagesStatistics -il QB_1_ortho.tif -out EstimateImageStatisticsQB1.xml
call otbcli_ComputeImagesStatistics -il QB_2_ortho.tif -out EstimateImageStatisticsQB3.xml
call otbcli_ComputeImagesStatistics -il QB_3_ortho.tif -out EstimateImageStatisticsQB3.xml
```

and then type `Test.bat` at the prompt in the OSGeo4W shell.  This was tested on Windows 7 and 8.